# error C3861: 'getLine': identifier not found

Tags: c++, string, getline

I've started programming abstractions (CS106B) from SEE. I'm having a hard time starting the assignment. Here's the code for the warmup exercise. I've already consulted various different solutions but none of them worked, hence, was compelled to post this here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "console.h"
using namespace std;

/* Constants */

const int HASH_SEED = 5381;               /* Starting point for first cycle */
const int HASH_MULTIPLIER = 33;           /* Multiplier for each cycle      */
const int HASH_MASK = unsigned(-1) >> 1;  /* All 1 bits except the sign     */

/* Function prototypes */

int hashCode(string name);

/* Main program to test the hash function */

int main() {
   string name = getLine("Please enter your name: ");
   int code = hashCode(name);
   cout << "The hash code for your name is " << code << "." << endl;
   return 0;
}

/*
 * Function: hash
 * Usage: int code = hashCode(key);
 * --------------------------------
 * This function takes the key and uses it to derive a hash code,
 * which is nonnegative integer related to the key by a deterministic
 * function that distributes keys well across the space of integers.
 * The general method is called linear congruence, which is also used
 * in random-number generators.  The specific algorithm used here is
 * called djb2 after the initials of its inventor, Daniel J. Bernstein,
 * Professor of Mathematics at the University of Illinois at Chicago.
 */

int hashCode(string str) {
   unsigned hash = HASH_SEED;
   int nchars = str.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < nchars; i++) {
      hash = HASH_MULTIPLIER * hash + str[i];
   }
   return (hash & HASH_MASK);
}
```

Compilation log:

```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: Warmup, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Warmup.cpp
1>c:\users\users\google drive\courses\programming abstractions (stanford cs106b) 2012\assignments\assignment1-vs2008\assignment1-vs2008\0-warmup\src\warmup.cpp(30) : error C3861: 'getLine': identifier not found
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Users\Google Drive\Courses\Programming Abstractions (Stanford CS106B) 2012\Assignments\Assignment1-vs2008\Assignment1-vs2008\0-Warmup\Warmup\Debug\BuildLog.htm"

1>Warmup - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `getLine()` isn't a standard C or C++ function.  There are various forms of `getline()` in the C++ standard library and the POSIX C library.  C is a case-sensitive language; so is C++. Also, dual-tagging with C and C++ leads to ire (on the part of those trying to respond) or confusion (on the part of those trying to understand) because they are very different languages.

Comment: Googling "C++ getLine" leads me directly to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: @chris `getline` is not `getLine`…

Comment: @user3477950, `getLine` is non-existent as far as we know. I'd put money on it being a typo/misunderstanding. And it seems I'm wrong on that front :p

Comment: Hi, my apologies for having so many mistakes in the question and tags. I'm a first-time user so will need some time to get acquainted to the website. SEE stands for (Stanford Engineering Everywhere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick rummage through the documentation for [Stanford's C++ library](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/cppdoc/), found through the home page for CS106B (I know it sounds implausible, but it's true), reveals that you should

```
 #include "simpio.h"
```

I recommend that you bookmark the documentation; it will save you from many late-night homework panics.

Comment: Phew. Thanks. I should've been able to see through it. Anyway, thanks for the solution as well as advice!

Answer (score 3):

First of all you you have to include header `<string>` instead of `<cstring>`

```
#include <string>
```

and secondly to use `getline` instead of `getLine`. And the type and number of arguments are specified incorrectly. Maybe you wanted to use some other user-defined function getLine.